# Oracle 12C In Ubuntu 14.04 : HOW Resolve [INS-32012] Unable to create directory: /u01/app/oracle

Tags: 14.04, oracle

I was following this [Site](http://www.techienote.com/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu/) for installing Oracle 12c on my Ubuntu 14.04.But I was stuck in the middle of the installation for the following step:

[image]

[image]

I used following commands to get permission but still didn't worked:

```
sudo chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01
chown -Rf oracle:dba /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
chown -Rf oracle:dba /u01/app/oracle
```

How can i solve this problem.please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think i found the answer.
check the user account permissions
the new oracle user create i guess will be
drwx------. 1 oracle oinstall 142 Mar 10 03:16 oracle

which means only the owner has read, write, and execute permissions.

changing that will solve the issue
not recommended though but this should fix the issue

chown 766 oracle

Answer (score 1):

I've used these steps and they are effective
لقد استخدمت هذه الخطوات وهي فعالة

to know the current user and group

> > id

To make the current user have the necessary permissions to write in the folder
myuser:1000,  mygroup:1000, folder=app

> > sudo chown -R 1000:1000 app